# QString Resets after appending 10 characters

Tags: c++, qt

I just started QT Language. A strange error occurred when I tried appending a character 10 times to it. It resets and starts over. Does anyone know a solution?

```cpp
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
    #include<string>
    #include<iostream>
    
    // First Number / Second Number
    double num1, num2;
    // Action s-substract a-add n-none
    char act;
    // Result
    double result;
    
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
        , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
    }
    
    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }



    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_16_clicked()
    {
        // Test Button
        AppendToLabel(2);
    }

QString tempLabel = "0";

void MainWindow::AppendToLabel(int s){
    //QString LabelText = ui->displayText->text();

    //testCase
    QString LabelText = tempLabel;

    // Updates the label acording to the button
    if(tempLabel.toInt() == 0)
    {
        // If the Number 0 present in the label - Rplace it
        LabelText = QString::number(s);
    }
    else
    {
        // If not not - Append it to the label
        LabelText.append(QString::number(s));
    }

    double apendedNumber = LabelText.toDouble();
    qDebug() << LabelText;
    tempLabel = LabelText;
    //ui->displayText->setText(LabelText);
}
```

When I append the 11th character, it replaces the whole string instead of appending it to the existing one.

I Updated the question with the full code. that needs to reproduce the error. When I pressed the Button 10 times, It correctly appends to the label as "2222222222". But as soon as I pressed the 11 time, it replaces as "2".

[image: Image of the OutPut]

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: How many characters are in "2147483647"?

Comment: This overload will work for 64 bit integers but you need to change from your 32 bit int to a 64 bit one: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qstring.html#number-5](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qstring.html#number-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 32-bit integer value can have a maximum value of `2^31 - 1`, or `2147483647`, which happens to be 10 digits long. So an 11 digit number would fail when calling `toInt()`.

```
QString s = "12345678901"
qDebug() << s.toInt();  // prints '0'
```